# How can hide directory name from the url using htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

For example I have url like
http://localhost/Experiments/login/login.php

I have hide the extention of file putting below code in .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.png -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.png
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.css -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.css
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.js -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.js
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.jpg -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.jpg
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.ico -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.ico
```

how can I make the above url to http://localhost/login
Even I tried for the solutions related to the same issue in stackoverflow but could not make it

Comment: yes, I don't want to show the folder names and file extension in the url @anubhava

Comment: Is it needed only for `/Experiments/login/login.php` file or for all the php files in `/Experiments/login/` directory?

Comment: all the php files in the Experiments/login/ directory @anubhava

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert this rule **just below `RewriteEngine On` line**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/Experiments/login/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ Experiments/login/$1.php [L]

# remaining rules go below this
```